# Uk tv sci fi show "never go after a wounded mouse"

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched this sometime between 1970 and 1974.
Saw it in Black and white (however my parents didn't have a colour set back then so it may well have been shown in colour)

Two spacemen have landed on some planet where all live in giant towers. The elite on top floors and more crowded the lower you get until basement levels are almost shoulder to shoulder.

Outside and between the towers is generations of garbage under a fierce sun, this has caused vermin and small animals to mutate into giants. Some of the high level tower people are discussing a recent 'safari' to the outside they made for big game hunting. Hence the phrase one used "never go after a wounded mouse"

I think the two spacemen cause some kind of social unrest by getting some lower people into the top tower levels "look at all these cubic feet of living space they have up here"

At the end they are back in their spacecraft getting ready for launch in a very heavy rainstorm, the view moves back and a giant terrier dog is in actuality urinating onto  their rocket amidst piles of rubbish.

Not sure if this was a one-off or a series, thanks.

Comment: Even if shown in the UK it must have surely been American from the moose reference?

Comment: @TheMathemagician What moose.

Comment: It was a giant mouse. Rats and mice and small dogs etc had all mutated into giant sizes

Comment: This might be an episode of "Out of the Unknown"(1966-1971 BBC TV series).  it was mostly stories adapted from American sci-fi authors.It's available on DVD but only region 2? and won't play on US players, and also many of the episodes are lost forever due to being scrapped by the BBC. It's available on Amazon.

Comment: Thanks "The Guest". I've spent a bit of time online since your comment digging into the episodes of Out of the Unknown but it doesn't look like the show I saw is amongst them.  Cheers anyway

Comment: @Danny3414. Okay, this one has me perplexed. It was an episode of a show, then? You saw it on the BBC, so was it British, American or some other country? Do you remember any accents? Was it supposed to be a comedy? Was it shot on video tape or film? Could this have been a kids show?

Comment: It was uk accents (one could have been Scottish) and was probably on itv - not BBC-  my dad  really didn't care for BBC and dad's ruled in those days. It may have been a comedy drama (no laugh track iirc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question (thanks to somebody over on another site)
Info from Wikipedia....

> The Adventures of Don Quick is a science fiction comedy television series that ran from October–December 1970, on ITV.
>   Starring Ian Hendry and Ronald Lacey, six 50 minute episodes were made, shown in a 60-minute time slot. As of 2008, only the first episode exists.
>
> The show was a science fiction satire based on the characters of Don Quixote, with astronaut Captain Don Quick (Ian Hendry) and Sergeant Sam Czopanser (Ronald Lacey), members of the "Intergalactic Maintenance Squad".
>
> On each planet they visit, Quick attempts to set right imaginary wrongs, often upsetting the inhabitants of whatever society he is in.

Episode 3 plot:-

> The Higher The Fewer. The pair land on Melkion 5 where the population live in 2,000 storey high skyscrapers. The upper floors are for the upper classes and the lower floors for the lower classes. Quick decides to change all of that with disastrous results.